# generating key with password and salt then encryping data with this key (php)

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to send a data to an API. They wants it as encrypted before send it over.

The **documentation** says:

1. Generate a private key using AES algorithm(with SHA-1 HMac function by PKCS 5 V2.0 Scheme - I DON'T know what this means.
2. Encrypt the data with this key (data is json_string) (PADDING_PKCS1 = 11 and key length is 2048bit)
3. Encrypt the private_key using RSA algorithm with the public key(they gave us a pem file)
4. Then send this encrypted datas in a json format.

They also gives a dll file. So I decompiled it, and it uses a library called BouncyCastle.

**Their function is basicly does this;**

```
this.aesService.GenerateKey(password_variable, salt_file_contents_as_bytes); (they gives that both)
byte[] data1 = this.aesService.Encode(json_string);
byte[] data2 = this.rsaService.Encode(this.aesService.GetAesKey(), reads_public_keys_data_as_byte);
// and some http requests nothing special
```

**What I tried is;**

1- generated a key using **openssl_pbkdf2** function with their password and salt

```
$key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 32, 20000, 'sha1');
```

2- encrypted the data with this key with **openssl_encrypt** function

```
$encryptedJson = openssl_encrypt($json_string, "AES256", $key);
```

3- encrypted the key that I generate with their public key with **openssl_public_encrypt** function

```
openssl_public_encrypt($key, $encryptedAes, $public_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

4- convert this results to hex with bin2hex function and send it to them

```
$jsonData = bin2hex($encryptedJson);
$keyData = bin2hex($encryptedAes);
```

But it returns error (*says invalid object -I don't know what this means*). I asked them about it but they didn't reply yet.

**What I want to ask you is:**

Am I doing it right? Am I using the right functions for this operations?

**EDIT:**

They still didn't reply back. But I just added the IV to the the start of the encrypted data returned by the openssl_encrypt function and convert it to hex. Voilà! It worked.

Comment: I'd be surprised if they encode to hex. You need to figure out the encoding, maybe look at what is send to the service using a  proxy or something like WireShark. I don't see much wrong with your code. Their description on the other hand sucks. I think you guessed PBKDF2 correctly. But it's a guess, they need to update their description.

Comment: Doesnt https do all this for you?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Good idea man, thank you. Documentation is really bad and they dont answer your call or reply your mail. And sadly, it's a official government service.

Comment: @Fikret is it possible to post the working code? we followed your foot steps however we are having the same error - invalid object . `$key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, file_get_contents('salt.dat'), 32, 20000, 'sha1');$cipher = "AES256"; $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher)); $encryptedJson = openssl_encrypt($json_content, "AES256", $key, $options=0, $iv); openssl_public_encrypt($key, $encryptedAes, file_get_contents('RsaPublicKey.pem'), OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING); $jsonData = bin2hex($encryptedJson); $keyData = bin2hex($encryptedAes);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public $json = '[
{
  "parola": "123456",
  "kullaniciKodu": "kullanici1",
  "doktorTc": "11111111111",
  "doktorMedulaPassword": "pass1",
  "receteAltTuru": "1",
  "takipNo": "tkp1",
  "hastaTc": "11111111111",
  "hastaGsm": "0",
  "tesisKodu": "11000001",
  "protokolNo": "A461942",
  "provizyonTip": "0",
  "doktorSertifikaKodu": "109",
  "doktorBransKodu": "9999",
  "hastaneReferansNumarasi": "0",
  "receteUrunTuru": "3",
  "taniListesi": [
    {
      "taniKodu": "K21"
    }
  ],
  "TibbiCihazListesi": [
    {
      "tibbiCihazSutKodu": "DO1005",
      "adet": 1,
      "periyod": 1,
      "periyodBirimi": 1,
      "kullanimSekli": 1,
      "kullanimYeri": "1"
    }
  ]
}]';

$password = "ZJ=ENY'2H+0bm'oyIe6J";
$salt = file_get_contents('salt.dat');
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('RenkliRsaPublicKey.pem'));

$key = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 32, 20000, 'sha1');

$cipher = "AES256";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$encryptedJson = openssl_encrypt($json, "AES256", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

openssl_public_encrypt($key, $encryptedAes, $public_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);


$jsonData = bin2hex($iv . $encryptedJson);
$keyData = bin2hex($encryptedAes);

gonder($jsonData, $keyData);


function gonder($encryptedJson, $encryptedAes) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://recetem.enabiz.gov.tr/Api/GetToken/v3.1/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
      "encryptedJson": "' . $encryptedJson . '",
      "encryptedAes": "' . $encryptedAes . '"
            }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Content-Type: text/plain'
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);
  echo $response;
}
```

Result: "v3.1 api metodunda hastaAdi, hastaSoyadi, hastaDogumTarihi, hastaCinsiyeti alanları zorunludur!"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).